# Why is my list function only outputting first value of my array?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, list

I'm still a php novice...I apologize if this is a silly question.

I have an array of numerical values ('views'), each 'view' specific to a video. I want to output the top 'views' into cells of a table (html). Whether my list is ascending or descending, I continue to only see the first number (but the correct number) of the list ($views1 in the first row). Here is my code:

```
<? php //lots of code, followed by

include 'connect.php';
$views=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT video.views FROM video ORDER by  
video.views DESC LIMIT 10"));   
list($views1,$views2,$views3,$views4,$views5,$views6,$views7,$views8,$views9,$views10)  
= $views;
?>

<html>
<body>
<table>
<tr><td><?php echo $views1 ?></td></tr>
<tr><td><?php echo $views2 ?></td></tr>
. //My actual code has 10 rows going from $views1 to $views10 
.
. 
<tr><td><?php echo $views10 ?></td></tr>

</body>
</html>
```

I just cannot see what the problem is...thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should work:

```
<?php //lots of code, followed by

include 'connect.php';
$q=mysql_query("SELECT video.views FROM video ORDER by video.views DESC LIMIT 10");
$views=array();
while ($views[]=mysql_fetch_array($q));
?>

<html>
  <body>
    <table>
        <?php
        foreach ($views as $view)
            echo '<tr><td>'.$view['views'].'</td></tr>';
        ?>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Don't forget that you shouldn't write duplicate codes, loops are there for you.

Comment: This code worked perfectly....I will repeat it for the left column of this table. Thanks for your help Javid!

Answer (score 0):

use

```
var_dump($views);
```

before your list(...) statement to debug it. It may be $views isn't being populated like you think.

Answer (score 0):

That's because `mysql_fetch_array` fetches *one* row, so even assigning a list of variables in this manner will only set as much as there is colunms in the result - one, in your case. Use something like that instead:

```
$res = mysql_query(...);
while ($arr = mysql_fetch_array($res)) $views[] = $arr[0];


<tr><td><?=$views[0]?></td></tr>
...
```

By the way, mysql extension is deprecated, use mysqli instead.